# Pixel Error Because Of Columns between Row Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]I have a structure like Row(Column1,Column2) but when i try to put a floating button to my column2, i get pixelError, how can make spaceless between columns ?                     [image: Here is the crash] and this is what im trying to do

```
Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
                    ),

                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 60.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: data.size.width * 80 / 100,
                        height: data.size.height * (20 / 100),
                        child: principalField,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(height: 30,
                    width: 30,
                      child: FloatingActionButton(
                        elevation: 40,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Column(children: <Widget>[
                 child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){},)
                ],)
              ],
            )),
```

Comment: Try using     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start     for the row.

Comment: their is no child properly in column->children widget

Comment: didn' t understand what you saying @VirenVVarasadiya

Comment: Column(children: <Widget>[
                 child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){},)
                ],) ? this is not valid code.

Comment: there's also a container, i miscopied my original code

Comment: it's not working @ArshShaikh

Comment: I have quite a few ideas, but before that just let me know what exactly are you trying to create. An image would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing what you want to do, this might be a better way of doing it.

Looks like this:
[image]

Just a snippet that I wrote for you to see and potentially use:

```
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        const SizedBox(
          height: 80,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 60,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(elevation: 40, onPressed: () {}),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 40,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 60,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(elevation: 40, onPressed: () {}),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 40,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 60,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(elevation: 40, onPressed: () {}),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good to know that it helped.